# Statistical Learning--Classification model with LASSO prediction error

Tags: r, machine-learning, missing-data, lasso-regression

I developed a LASSO model on training data to predict a binary response variable in R, using cross-validation to select my $\lambda$:

```
x = model.matrix(y ~ x1 + x2 + ... + x23, data=train)[, -1]
library(glmnet)
glm.train = glmnet(x, y = as.factor(train$y), alpha = 1, family = 'binomial')
```

plot(glm.train, xvar = "lambda")
grid()
glm.train.cv = cv.glmnet(x, y = train$dem, alpha = 1, family = 'binomial')
    opt.lambd = glm.train.cv$lambda.min
train.fit.lasso = glmnet(x, y = train$dem, alpha = 1, family = 'binomial')
    predict(train.fit.lasso, s = opt.lambd, type = "coefficients")[1:23, ]

I then tested the model on test data, which yielded solid results (below, I've inserted my ROC curve for the model on the test data):
[image]

In both my training and test data used above, I had actual values for the response variable, and was able to use the `model.matrix()` function to compute prediction values. However, I have a second section of test data in which every value for the response variable is NA. After applying the `model.matrix()` on this data, the dimension of my matrix is 0x22:

```
> dim(x.predict)
[1]  0 22
```

I've tried a few alternatives to `model.matrix()`, but just get errors. For example, when I try to use `data.matrix()`, the dimensions of my matrix are correct:

```
> x.predict = data.matrix(predict.data[c(-1,-2,-3, -5,-6, -10, -14, -18,-19, -21, -26,-27, -34,-35,-36,-37)])
> dim(x.predict)
[1] 5010   23
```

However, I receive the following error when I try to estimate probabilities or classifications using my model:

```
> test$test.probs = predict(train.fit.lasso, newx = x.predict, s = opt.lambd, type = "response")
```

Error in as.matrix(cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta : 
  Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90

> test$test.predicts = predict(train.fit.lasso, newx = x.predict[1:5010,], s = opt.lambd, type = "class")
>       Error in as.matrix(cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta) : 
>         error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta : 
>         Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90

Has anyone encountered this problem before with LASSO? Or, could someone help me understand how the different `.matrix()` functions are used with LASSO and a possible work around for calculating predictions when the response values are NA?